# Converter certificado cer sem PK em PCKS12

Tags: java, certificado-digital, openssl

Possuo um Certificado em minha conta e preciso exportá-lo para fazer a autenticação em um site - seguindo estes procedimentos: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication). Só que na importação no windows, ele não exporta junto com a chave privada. Como devo proceder? Já realizei o seguinte procedimento:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in certificate.cer -out pkcs12.pfx
```

e o mesmo retorna uma mensagem de erro:

96864:error:0D0C6070:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_pack:encode error:asn_pack.c:170: unable to write 'random state'

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro ?

Comment: 96864:error:0D0C6070:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_pack:encode error:asn_pack.c:170:
unable to write 'random state'

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o erro lá por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi do link passado, o comando para gerar o p12 foi:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12 -name "Whatever"
```

No próprio link, fala que a chave privada do cliente precisa também ser incluída. Faltou esse comando para incluir a chave privada e publica sua. E só para confirmar, o arquivo crt ou cer com o certificado público do site precisa ter toda a cadeia.

**Solução**

Para esse problema, foi utilizado o [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ola, nao possuo chave privata. por isso do uso de -nokeys.

Comment: Talvez seja necessário gerar uma com `openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048`

Comment: Pode usar a ferramenta [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/). Dá para gerar a private key e importar os certificados do servidor. Pode também exportar para p12 ou para java keystore.

Comment: usando o comando do openssl, aconteceu o seguinte erro: Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
....................+++
.........+++
unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)

Comment: Tem algum problema no comando openssl. Tenta usar o portecle, ele é feito em java e não utiliza o openssl.

Comment: Ok, usei portecle. Criei um novo keystore e importe o cer para dentro dele.